# Telnet alert on SIEM

Tags: monitoring, siem

We are currently setting up the McAfee SIEM. Some rules have been set up using signature ID. Below is the alarm that triggers frequently:

```
Summary: Signature ID 'Suspicious - Remote Shell Communication with Suspicious Host - Event or Flow' (47-4000180) match found The following events were found
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

Source IP = 93.116.127.108                // below is the list of source IPs 
Destination IP = 135.10.194.xxx           //(xxx-changes)  


93.116.127.108
106.186.31.135
106.184.2.29
61.150.126.243
46.151.52.231
122.52.49.214
169.228.66.91
60.248.45.40
106.184.2.29
106.186.31.135
47.18.82.224
71.6.146.186
106.186.31.135
175.193.11.61
106.186.31.135

Source Port = 38974 
Destination Port = 23

pass 1

Source User = Root (Always)
Destination User = (Blank always)

Source Geolocation=Chisinau, Chisinau, Moldova, unknown
Destination Geolocation=*****************, United States, ********

Eventcount = 1

First Event - 04/11/2016 23:19:52
Last Event - 04/11/2016 23:19:52

Message - Suspicious - Remote Shell Communication with Suspicious Host - Event or Flow

Application - telnet
Average Severity = 75
Signature ID = 47-4000180
```

Please help me understand, why am I getting this and what should be done to resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it looks like an attacker is trying to send commands to your system via Telnet (port 23). Which brings up the question: why are you using Telnet?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking for. It's alerting on commands being sent to telnet (port 23). Do you have port 23 open? Is telnet running?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like someone is probably trying to brute force usernames/passwords or other  malicious [connections](http://www.howtohackin.com/blog/introduction-to-reconnaissance-part-2-a-deeper-look-at-port-scanning/) to your host.  Either way you should never have telnet open because it is very insecure.  You need to disable port 23 immediately on your host.